# multiple targets in make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What does the following rule mean?

```
$(PROGRAM33).o: $(SYSDIR)/%.o: storeapp%.cpp
                @echo Compiling $< ...
```

Is it equal to the following

```
$(SYSDIR)/%.o: storeapp%.cpp
                @echo Compiling $< ...

$(PROGRAM33).o: $(SYSDIR)/%.o
```

Comment: This seems to be a static pattern rule, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718701/1741542 and [Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)

Comment: @OlafDietsche:- Thanks. If this comment becomes the answer i will accept it.

Comment: Since it's not my answer, I suggest, you upvote the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this sort of makefile:

```
f1.png: d/p1.xml
f2.png: d/p2.xml
f3.png: d/p3.xml

f1.png f2.png f3.png:
    some-interesting-tool $^ -o $@
```

Here we have chosen to write the shell line only once, listing the dependencies separately.

Since, in this case, the targets (`f%.png`) are related to their dependencies (`d/p%.xml`) via (the simple minded) make patterns, we can shorten this boiler-plate thus:

```
f1.png f2.png f3.png: f%.png: d/p%.png
    some-interesting-tool $^ -o $@
```

This is a static pattern rule. Much nicer than ordinary pattern rules IMHO. They have the nice property that whatever the `%` matched in the rule, is available as `$*` in the recipe.

Note that, not unreasonably, the target pattern must match each of the source files. In your case therefore, each of `${PROGRAM33}.o` (probably expands to a single file) must be matched by `${SYSDIR}/%.o`.